# Is there a shortcut for showing (or hiding) all characters in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

If find seeing all characters useful in the following two scenarios:

1. When I want to see the characters which start a newline `CR` (\r) and `LF` (\n)
2. For checking a python code for tabs and 4 spaces (basically to distinguish between the two)

That's where the Notepad++ feature to *show all characters* comes in handy. It would have been even more convenient if there were to be a keyboard shortcut for the same. I wasn't able to find one using Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notepad++ allows you to customize your shorcuts. You simply need to go to the `Settings` menu and then go to the `Shortcut Mapper` option.

You can check out [this tutorial](http://www.martinrinehart.com/frontend-engineering/engineers/tools/notepad-pp/shortcuts.html).

Comment: Great advice! Took me about 1 minute to make it work!